# java equivalent of dynamically allocated arrays in C++

Tags: java, c++, arrays

I'm learning java after having programmed in C++ for a while, and I'm wondering if you can dynamically allocate an array in java as you do in C++.

Say in C++ we do:

```
int* array = new int[arraySize]; //allocate an array
delete[] array;                  //delete it
```

Can you do the same in java or is there a java equivalent that basically does the same thing? Thanks!

Comment: `Java` don't have pointers.

Comment: yes, you can do the same thing with Java (well, by following the Java syntax) and let the GC worry about freeing your memory.

Comment: What are you calling "dynamic". To me, this term is related to data structures able to grow, unlike the arrays.

Comment: I completely agree with @Dici. You are still allocating data on the heap based on a value which is resolved at compile time.

Comment: In C++ we prefer `std::vector<int> v(arraySize);` because you don't have to `delete` it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. With small syntax correction,

```
int arraySize = 10; // may resolve at runtime even
int[] array = new int[arraySize];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create new arrays using

```
int[] myNewArray = new int[myArraySize]; // myArraySize being an int
```

or use List like [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) which are resizable.

In java, deletion is made by the garbage collector. So you usually don't call any methods to manually remove your objects.

To do so, you can simply change the reference to null

```
myNewArray = null;
```

The next time the garbage collector is called, it may delete the "array" object.
You can also manually notiy the garbage collector using

```
System.gc();
```

But you can't be sure your object will be deleted at this time.

Comment: op is asking about allocating and freeing memory. here is the freeing memory part